# dark mode on multiple views and problems had during implementation of dark mode iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, ios-darkmode

I would like to implement a iOS dark mode testing with 3 options: light, dark, and system. The first two will force the app in that particular state and not follow the system settings.

Right now I would like to implement this settings in multiple views instead of single view, and i created the options in my second view. But I have two problems faced right now:

1. The "light" and "dark" only affects the second view instead of all views.
2. I use present modally for the storyboard segue. When I change my options from "system" to "dark" in my second view, it change to dark mode. But if I close the second view and open again by clicking the self-defined button, it shows back to the status of "system".

Below is my code for second view

```
import UIKit

class DarkModeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var darkModeTable: UITableView!

    var statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default { didSet { setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() } }
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { statusBarStyle }
    
    let mode = ["Light", "Dark", "System"]
    var currentStatus = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        switch currentStatus {
        case "Light":
            overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
            statusBarStyle = .darkContent
            break
        case "Dark":
            overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
            statusBarStyle = .lightContent
            break
        case "System":
            overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .unspecified
            statusBarStyle = .default
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        
        darkModeTable.dataSource = self
        darkModeTable.delegate = self
    }
    
    // Table View Data Source method
     func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
     }
    
     // Table View Data Source method
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mode.count
     }

     // Table View Data Source method
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
     cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
     -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell: UITableViewCell!

         //take a cell from the queue of reusable cells
         cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
         withIdentifier: "tableCell")

         //if there are no reusable cells
         if cell == nil {

             // create a new cell
             cell = UITableViewCell(
             style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default,
             reuseIdentifier: "tableCell")
         }

         // set the textLabel for the cell
         cell!.textLabel!.text = mode[indexPath.row]
        
        if (overrideUserInterfaceStyle == .light){
            if (mode[indexPath.row] == "Light"){
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                currentStatus = "Light"
            }
            else{
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            }
        }
        else if (overrideUserInterfaceStyle == .dark){
            if (mode[indexPath.row] == "Dark"){
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                currentStatus = "Dark"
            }
            else{
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            }
        }
        else if (overrideUserInterfaceStyle == .unspecified){
            if (mode[indexPath.row] == "System"){
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                currentStatus = "System"
            }
            else{
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            }
        }

         // return the Table View Cell
         return cell!
     }

    // Table View Delegate method
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
    didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        //clear previous stored chacked indexPath
        for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) {
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: indexPath.section)) {
                cell.accessoryType = row == indexPath.row ? .checkmark : .none
            }
        }
        
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
            statusBarStyle = .darkContent
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
            statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 2)
        {
            overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .unspecified
            statusBarStyle = .default
        }
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    }

}
```

Comment: try to with the current status in viewWilAppear method.

Comment: do you mean in the second view?

Comment: in the viewDidload you have a switch with current status try to move that block of code to viewVillAppear and try

Comment: I tried, but it doesnt work